# Regular expression working only irregular

Tags: regex, perl

Coding in Perl and got the following piece of code, trying to match words with at least two letters as well as the ending character being a "Z"

```
if($_ =~ m/w{2,}z$/ig)
```

The file I'm reading from contains the following words:

```
ahahahahahahahahahahaz
sfafafasfasfasfsvxcvcxZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstz
```

Only `sfafafasfasfasfsvxcvcxZ` is being recognized. 
What am I missing here?

Also, I would like to retrieve cases where the word might be:
`thisisaword-iwanttoberecognizedZ` would it suffice to write the code as
  `if($_ =~ m/D{2,}z$/ig)`

Comment: The `m/w{2,}z$/` looks for two or more of `w` then a `z` then end of string. Have you copied the regular expression correctly? Did you mean `m/\w{2,}z$`? The `g` after the match is not useful or necessary. Please provide a minimal example of code that we can run and that shows the problem you are getting. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w{2,}` means you want to see twice a `w`. Try `\w{2,}`, which means you want two word characters (letters):

```
if($_ =~ m/\w{2,}z$/ig)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really that easy. Hate to screw up the easy stuff. Cheers!